# Excel sort/filter

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

Excel novice here. I have  a large Excel table that I need to sort for each occurrence of a text value. For example I need to view the entire row each time "Bob" appears in a range of D2 through Z50. If I filter only column D I will see only those instances where "Bob" is in column D. If he appears in column J I won't see it. How can I see every time "Bob" appears within the range and filter everyone else out?

Answer (score 0):

In **AA2**  enter:

```
=MIN(COUNTIF(D2:Z2,"Bob"),1)
```

and copy down thru **AA50**

Then apply an AutoFilter displaying rows in which cells in column **AA** display 1